# Am I using CocosDenshion correctly?

Tags: iphone, audio, cocos2d-iphone

I have found a tonne of leaks in my code. All of them come about when I play a sound or a song.

Here is how I call a sound effect:

```
 [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"myeffect.wav"];
```

Here is how I play a song:

```
 [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"mysong.mp3"];
```

Am I somehow supposed to be releasing these after they are finished or something?

Comment: I have the same problem, and searching for solutions... and will post answer when I find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using it right. Are you sure you have a memory leak? `SimpleAudioEngine` will cache the audio file you play, for subsequent plays, so maybe that's why you see the memory increase and not decrease afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

To get the memory back, you need to call unloadEffect: on the SimpleAudioEngine.

See http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_simple_audio_engine.html#a1f3f121b3664c6b5bcfc33c8af63e52c